# Can swapping be disabled on the application level?

Tags: encryption, swap

I'm currently using thunderbird with gnupg to read encrypted emails.
If I understand the swapping behavior correctly, the memory pages containing the decrypted emails might be swapped out and leave traces on the hard disk which may in theory later be recovered forensically.

While it is certainly possible to just use an encrypted swapfile or disable swapping globally for the duration of using sensitive files, it impacts performance, might be forgotten and requires root privileges.

Is it possible to mark certain files or programs as not to be swapped? Even without root access? Could one write an application which can be distributed to technically naive users and whose memory contents are never swapped to disk?

Comment: [Related](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77939/turning-off-swapping-for-only-one-process-with-cgroups) essentially you would create a cgroup, tune swappiness so that it would never swap out, and `cgexec` thunderbird into it. You still need root access, but that's the admin-level resolution. If you're developing your own application you would [use mlock](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mlock).

Comment: GPG may already call `mlock`, you should check.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about cgroups yet, they sound interesting.

Comment: @SteveWills [It does.](https://www.gnupg.org/faq/GnuPG-FAQ.html) Not sure about thunderbird though, which is displaying the decrypted result.

Comment: @Bratchley, can you put it in an answer? I didn't know you could set swappiness for cgroups, it sounds intriguing.

Comment: @frostschutz posted an answer. `memory.swappiness=0` may not be a perfect solution but it may resolve the issue at a practical level.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the comments, I suggested you create a cgroup, set `memory.swappiness` to zero (to minimize swapping) and run your application inside of that. If you did that, your application *probably* wouldn't swap unless you were running so incredibly low on physical memory that swapping pages for programs in that cgroup was the only way to make enough physical memory available.

To do this on RHEL 6.5:

- Ensure the `libcgroup` package is installed. This gives you access to userspace tools like  `cgcreate` and `cgexec`.
- Start and enable the `cgconfig` service so that changes to cgroup configuration are persistent between reboots. On RHEL this service should also mount the required filesystems underneath the `/cgroup` tree.
- Create the cgroup with `cgcreate -g memory:thunderbird`
- Set swappiness to zero in this group with `cgset -r memory.swappiness=0 thunderbird`
- Use `cgsnapshot -s > /etc/cgconfig.conf` to save an updated persistent configuration for the `cgconfig` service (all changes up until now have been runtime changes. You'll probably want to save the default config file somewhere and give it a once-over before making it the persistent configuration.
- You can now use `cgexec` to start desired applications within the `thunderbird` cgroup:

  [root@xxx601 ~]# cgexec -g memory:thunderbird ls

  anaconda-ks.cfg  a.out  foreman.log  index.html  install.log  install.log.syslog  node.pp  sleep  sleep.c  ssl-build  stack  test

  [root@xxx601 ~]#

I don't have `thunderbird` actually installed otherwise I would have done that. Not sure why the formatting of the above is messed up.

- One alternative to `cgexec` would be to start thunderbird and add the PID to the `tasks` file for the application. For example:

  [root@xxx601 ~]# cat /cgroup/memory/thunderbird/tasks

  [root@xxx601 ~]# pidof httpd

  25926 10227 10226 10225 10163 10162 10161 10160 10159 10157 10156 10155 10152 10109

  [root@xxx601 ~]# echo 25926 > /cgroup/memory/thunderbird/tasks

  [root@xxx601 ~]# cat /cgroup/memory/thunderbird/tasks

  25926

Again, it's bears mentioning that this doesn't technically prevent swapping but short of modifying the application itself, it's probably your best bet. I've just now found `memory.memsw.limit_in_bytes` which seems like it might be a more direct control on forcing there to be *no* swapping but I haven't played around with it enough to really feel comfortable saying that it fixes your problem completely. That said, it might be something to look into after this.

---

The real answer would be to have the application `mlock` sensitive information to get around this sort of concern. I'm willing to bet an application like Thunderbird, though, does do that but I don't know enough about the internals to comment on that.

Comment: To handle all of the other fs's that @Gilles mentions you'd want a `chroot` in an `unshare`d `--mount` namespace, as well, I think. Do that and I'm willing to bet the end performance effect would be better than an encrypted swap.

Comment: Yeah no doubt that an admin can only do so much, ultimately the application needs to take these sorts of things into consideration since there are so many and admin-level controls can get pretty elaborate.

Comment: Could a coredump still be inspected to reveal what goes on for an arbitrary process even if the `memory.swappiness=0` do you think? I wouldn't know - but I'm curious.

Comment: Yes but that's true of almost anything, including applications with mlock but don't `MADV_DONTDUMP`. Most of the time, though, people that are worried about swapping sensitive information are worried about laptops being stolen and the swap area being combed over. At the point they're initiating core dumps the system has already been completely compromised.

Answer (score 5):

Applications can lock their memory so it cannot be swapped.

```
mlock, munlock, mlockall, munlockall - lock and unlock memory
```

I don't know of a way to influence this from the outside, though. The application would have to be written to use this by itself. With mails it's probably particularly difficult since it usually also involves external programs for viewing attachments and such.

Also, even with memlock there is a chance of it ending up on your swap partition - when you use suspend to disk which writes all memory to disk, regardless of any non-swap preferences.

It's easier to just go full disk encryption in the first place.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, an application can prevent some of its memory from being swapped out, with the [`mlock`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mlock) system call. However, this is not really useful in your case.

Confidential data isn't just in application memory. It ends up in temporary files in various places (`/tmp`, `/var/spool`, etc.). Thunderbird itself is displaying the decrypted email, so you'd have to lock it to RAM too.

If you want to ensure that your disk won't contain traces of confidential files, you need to encrypt your swap as well as all the potential locations of temporary files (in particular, `/tmp` if it isn't tmpfs, and most of `/var`, in addition to your home directory of course).

The impact of encrypted swap on performance is small to nil. Encryption is a lot faster than disk I/O.

Comment: Seems a `chroot` and a namespace container with `swapoff` would be a better alternative to encrypted swap. Very good answer - no other answer mentioned other filesystem effects. Myself, I just don't have a `swap` - I don't own any computer with less than 4GBs of RAM, and I can't see any benefit to using it. Its use is only practical for any of those machines where suspend is concerned - and that is easily scripted.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just thinking if it would be better to start with changing the priority of the application process on e.g. with a start-up script starting it with a high priority using `nice` and `renice` and with the I/O priority change that with `ionice` and then see what happens.

You can 'nice' the application to the highest priority level e.g. `-20` that way you still leave the OS to do what it does best by making the decision on when to swap application processes.

But has suggested by others if you want more control and granularity you need to start looking at `cgroups` and setting `memory.swappiness`